# Bisect with discontinuous monotonous function: Find root using bisection for weakly monotonous function allowing for jumps

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, bisection

I'm looking for a Python algorithm to **find the root of a function `f(x)` using bisection**, equivalent to [scipy.optimize.bisect](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html#scipy-optimize-bisect), but **allowing for discontinuities (jumps) in `f`. The function `f` is weakly monotonous.**

It would be *nice but not necessary* for the algorithm to flag if the crossing (root) is directly 'at' a jump, and in this case to return the exact value `x` at which the relevant jump occurs (i.e. say the `x` for which `sign(f(x-e)) != sign(f(x+e))` and `abs(f(x-e)-f(x+e)>a` for infinitesimal `e>0` and non-infinitesimal `a>0`). It is also okay if instead the algorithm, for example, simply returns an `x` within a certain tolerance in this case.

As the function is only *weakly* monotonous, it can have flat areas, and theoretically these can occur 'at' the root, i.e. where `f=0`: `f(x)=0 for an entire range, x in [x_0,x_1]`. In this case again, *nice but not necessary* for the algo to flag this particularity, and to, say, ensure an `x` from the range `[x_0,x_1]` is returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you supply (possibly very small) strictly positive positives for `xtol` and `rtol`, the function will work with discontinuities:

```
import numpy as np
>>> optimize.bisect(f=np.sign, a=-1, b=1, xtol=0.0001, rtol=0.001)
0.0
```

If you look in the scipy codebase at the [C source code implementation of the function](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.4.1/scipy/optimize/Zeros/bisect.c) you can see that this is a very simple function that makes no assumptions on continuity. It basically takes two points which have a sign change, and switches to a smaller range with a sign change, until the iterations run out or the tolerances are met.

Given your requirements that functions *might* be discontinuous / flat, it is in fact *necessary* (for any algorithm) to supply these tolerances. Without them, it could be impossible for an optimization function to converge to a solution.